# Birt generating different PDF format for the same report

Tags: java, pdf, birt

I've a simple report with only one table and paper size set as A4. On the viewer the PDF format is correct but when generated by calling a Java class, the alignment is messed up. It has huge margin in right, tried setting margin to 0, align center... but no luck

Here is the Java code (I'm using Birt 4.4.0)

```
  PDFRenderOption pdfOptions = new PDFRenderOption();
  pdfOptions.setOutputFormat(RenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF); 
  pdfOptions.setEmitterID(RenderOption.OUTPUT_EMITTERID_PDF);
  pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, IPDFRenderOption.FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE);
  pdfOptions.setOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but maybe `FIT_TO_PAGE_SIZE` is causing your trouble.
In my Java program, I'm using these settings instead (and the reports are using a fixed layout):

```
pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, IPDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_TO_MULTIPLE_PAGES);

// Dafür sorgen, dass Texte nicht abgeschnitten werden, sondern umgebrochen:
pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_TEXT_WRAPPING, true);
pdfOptions.setOption(IPDFRenderOption.PDF_HYPHENATION, true);
```

Comment: Sorry I overlooked your answers while reading Birt documentation and forum. All this time the solution was in front of me. Thanks